# Smarty foreach counter , reset after 3 element

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I want to create foreach smarty loop with counter and  3 "if" conditions inside. 
After my counter value is more than 3 I want to reset counter value and get back to first condition of If

This is my code

```
{foreach $itemscollection as $singleitem name=smartyloop}
     {assign var="counter" value=$smarty.foreach.smartyloop.iteration}

     {if $counter == 1}
          <h1>I am the one</h1>
         {/if}
     {if $counter == 2}
         <h1>I am  second</h1>
     {/if}
     {if $counter == 3}
         <h1>I am  third</h1>
     {/if}
     {if $counter > 3}
     {$counter = 1}
     {/if]

 {/foreach}
```

So for example If I have 4 elements to place into foreach output should look like

```
I am the one
I am second
I am third 
I am the one
```

Now it's not working and i don't know why. 
Can somebody please help me and tell how to resolve that problem ?

Comment: that happens because you set value of counter to 1, and in a next step you again assign it to foreach loop iteration, try without assigning foreach iteration number, just increase your counter on the end of loop

Comment: You mean divide like {if $counter/3 == 1 } ? I think that will not work because 12 is divided by 2 and 3

Answer (score 5):

```
{assign var=counter value=1}
{foreach $itemscollection as $singleitem name=smartyloop}
      {if $counter == 1}
          <h1>I am the one</h1>
      {/if}
      {if $counter == 2}
          <h1>I am  second</h1>
      {/if}
      {if $counter == 3}
          <h1>I am  third</h1>
      {/if}
      {if $counter > 3}
          {assign var=counter value=1}
      {/if]

      {$counter++}
{/foreach}
```

this might work

Comment: It's not working , output is :                                                                        
            0
I am the one                                                 
            1

Comment: try now i changed it a bit

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old one but try to use counter as a custom function from smarty:

```
{foreach $itemscollection as $singleitem name=smartyloop}
    {counter assign='pos'} {* assign counter to variable *}

    {if $pos == 1}
        <h1>I am the one</h1>
    {/if}
    {if $pos == 2}
        <h1>I am  second</h1>
    {/if}
    {if $pos == 3}
        <h1>I am  third</h1>
        {counter start=0} {*reset counter*}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Had to go back to CMS Made Simple to make something related ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
{if $counter%3 eq 0 && $counter gt 2}
    {assign var=counter value=1}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use {cycle} http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.cycle.tpl

```
{cycle name="counter" values="1,2,3"}
```

Or you could use the Modulus(%) operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

```
{$counter = ($smarty.foreach.smartyloop.iteration % 3) + 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working 
I dont't know why , maybe foreach checks conditions from last to first .

```
  {foreach $blogscollection as $singleblog name=smartyloop}
                {assign var="counter" value=$smarty.foreach.smartyloop.iteration}
                {if $counter>3}
                    {assign var=counter value=1}
                {/if}
                {if $counter == 1}
                    <h1>I am the one</h1>
                {/if}
                {if $counter == 2}
                    <h1>I am the second</h1>
                {/if}
                {if $counter == 3}
                    <h1>I am the third</h1>
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$array=array(' the ','hap',' pop' ,' grand'); // assume this is your array to pass in for   each
$says=array(' the one','second',' third');  // store your word to appear
$count=0;
foreach ($array as $arr){
if($count == 3) $count=0;
 print "<h1>I am $says[$count]<h1>";
$count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Although the PHP tag was there, The original question mentions a Smarty foreach loop, not a PHP foreach loop